# Basic Scolling Question

Tags: android

Hey guys, im pretty new to android platform and have a really simple question. Im putting buttons as layouts with text boxes, but im running out of room. How would i make it possible for the user to scroll down to view more buttons and stuff. For example, if i have 6 buttons, and 3 are in the field of view, i wanna be able to scroll with my finger and be able to see those buttons as I scroll.

Thanks for the help guys

-Localgamer

Answer (score 0):

You can put your controls(widgets: buttons, labels etc) inside a ScrollView. Check the documentation of the class for details : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Something like:

```
<ScrollView ..>
   <TextView .../>
   <Button .../>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/proffrag"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="30dip"
                android:paddingRight="30dip"
                android:paddingTop="10dip" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/firstname"
                    style="@style/custom"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"

                    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/usernamem"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/firstname"
                    android:inputType="textCapWords"
                    android:singleLine="true" >

                    <requestFocus />
                </EditText>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="10dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/lastname"
                    style="@style/custom"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/usernamem"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/lastname"
                    android:inputType="textCapWords"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="10dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/username"
                    style="@style/custom"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_@-."
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/usernamem"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/username"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="10dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    style="@style/custom"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_@-.,"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/emailm"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="10dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/selecttopic"
                    style="@style/custom"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/selecttopic" />

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radiosubject"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/rbtn_selector"
                        android:button="@null"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Subject"
                        android:textColor="@drawable/rbtn_textcolor_selector" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radiocourse"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/rbtn_selector"
                        android:button="@null"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Courses"
                        android:textColor="@drawable/rbtn_textcolor_selector" />
                </RadioGroup>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="10dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/selectgen"
                    style="@style/custom"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/selectgen" />

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radiomale"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/rbtn_selector"
                        android:button="@null"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/selectmale"
                        android:textColor="@drawable/rbtn_textcolor_selector" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radiofemale"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/rbtn_selector"
                        android:button="@null"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/selectfemale"
                        android:textColor="@drawable/rbtn_textcolor_selector" />
                </RadioGroup>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="10dp" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/proftextgender"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/browse"
                        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/mycustom_button"
                        android:minHeight="40dp"
                        android:text="@string/browse"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/firs"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/browseimage"
                        android:layout_width="109dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.17"
                        android:maxLines="2" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/vi"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/firs" >
                </View>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/vi"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/upload"
                        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/mycustom_button"
                        android:minHeight="30dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                        android:paddingRight="20dp"
                        android:text="@string/upload"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                android:paddingRight="30dp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/savechagnes"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/mycustom_button"
                    android:minHeight="40dp"
                    android:text="@string/savechanges"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```